Create edges for a set of vertices with Geometry Nodes
I have a collection of vertices and I want to connect some of them by edges. I need to compare any possible pair of vertices and their attributes to decide, whether they should be connected.
How can I facilitate an operation acting on every possible pair of points/vertices of the geometry?
Would it be helpful to have an exact copy of the geometry?
I basically need to get a pair of indices, such that I can extrude one vertex into the direction of the other, once the pair is selected by some selection function.
Further information:
The vertices that are displayed on the screen are actually points that live in an eight-dimensional space. The full eight-dimensional coordinates are stored inside the attributes associated to every vertex. Whether two vertices are connected by a line depends on the distance of these vertices in the eight-dimensional space.
I want to go over each pair of vertices, evaluate there distances in eight-dimensions (just applying a function to the attributes of the pair). Depending on this evaluation an edge will be extruded between the pair of vertices.


" I need to compare any two pairs of vertices" - two pairs, or one pair = two verts? Can you describe why you need this to avoid an XY problem?

I changed the typo. Of course only one pair of verts. What do you mean with "XY problem"?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

This setup connects pairs of vertices, which sums of indices are divisible by $8$:



How do you get such a nice line structure in your geometry nodes setup?

@p6majo you can enable snapping in node editors.
